# How to cook egg whites?

Tags: eggs, egg-whites

I have bought a bottle of egg whites as I do not enjoy the yolks at all.

For normal eggs I'd either fry them on the pan (pour it on non-stick, flip it over sometime later or a few times and done) or boil till hard.

Is there any chance to get the whites into something hardened? The recipes on the internet mostly make scrambled eggs but I want it all in a single piece of white with a structure similar to boiled egg.

I tried pouring the egg whites on the pan but they burned to the pan and became unflippable. It ended up something similar to scrambled eggs (I tried higher and lower heats).

Then I tried to fry them using oil. It worked but it all tasted oily which was bad once again.

Then I tried pouring egg whites into the water similarly to how poached egg is made. It just dispersed throughout the water and became a fluffy, wattery mess of boiled egg scraps.

Comment: a simple egg poaching tray will do what you want. just lightly oil the divots in the poaching tray (this helps prevent sticking), then fill each with your egg white, then steam. image: https://kha.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Aluminium-Egg-Poacher-1.jpg

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you'd like a solution do with no expensive or difficult to find equipment, as would we all - so that's what I offer.

What you will need:

- A tin - as from soup or sweetcorn or tunafish. The only stipulation is that it should have straight sides, not crinkled.
- A little oil/butter.
- A saucepan, medium/small.
- A jug or beaker of water.
- A thin flexible knife to free the egg from the tin.

Firstly prepare the tin. Use a tin opener horizontaly to remove the top lip of the tin that is left after normal use.

Clean and dry the tin, then coat the interior surface with the oil/butter careful to not cut yourself on the sharp metal edge.

Pour the egg white into the tin, place the tin in the centre of the saucepan.

Using the jug, add water to the saucepan till the level is approximatley level with the surface of the eggwhite. Do this gently to avoid disturbing the tin.

Gently heat the saucepan until it simmers very gently, leaving the lid off the pan.

Wait. For every 50 mL of egg white, wait whilst it simmers for 6 minutes.

Turn the heat off.

Allow to cool enough to touch the water surface without burning yourself, don't rush this just let it cool naturaly.

Remove the tin from the water and gently invert on a plate.

Use the tin opener to pierce the base of the tin and gently shake the tin up and down with the plate till the egg releases, if it doesn't, you can turn the whole thing upside down and trace the inner side of the tin using the knife to free the egg, re-invert and gently shake till it releases.

Voila, you should now have an egg white cake.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to cook the egg whites in a plastic bag submerged in water.  For preference, I would use a [sturdy bag](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LCKD5QW) from a vacuum sealer (but without using the vacuum).  I don't have a recipe that I've tried, so you may have to experiment with timing.  When I hard cook whole eggs, I put them in cold water in a pan, bring it to a boil, immediately turn it off, and then let it sit for ten minutes.  If you can seal th whites into the bag with little air, and then roll the liquid into a cylinder about the thickness of an egg, the time should be close to what I do for a whole egg in the shell.

If you don't have a vacuum sealer, you could try using a 'freezer' zip-top bag and add it to boiling water that you then turn off.

I haven't actually tried these recipes with egg whites (or substitutes), so, if you try them, I'd love to see how they work for you.

Answer (score 3):

## Coonass Egg "Sous-vide en Carton"

> I tried pouring the egg whites on the pan but they burned to the pan and became unflippable. It ended up something similar to scrambled eggs (I tried higher and lower heats).

Almost like in [Van's post here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/95424/21697), when I was working out all the time I ate a LOT of egg whites. Normally, I used an egg-white seperator to separate the yolks, and then I donated them to the neighbor's pye dog. But, if you want to know another way to cook eggs I suggest cooking them **in the carton**.

Buy a carton of Egg Whites. They should come bout 2 pints in a carton. Cook half em' classy. Then for the other half, place half the carton of the eggs whites back in the carton. Boil a small pot of water. Put the carton in the pot of boiling water.

Now for the magic. Just wait for 10 minutes. Then split the carton down the center with your pocket knife, open it up, and serve with orange juice. Eat them plain or add some [Tony Chachere's creole seasoning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IXQQXTU).

Comment: Brilliant!  And uses even fewer supplies than my idea.

Comment: What does "cook half 'em classy" actually mean?

Comment: @elbrant Cooking eggs "classy" is parish for taking eggs out of the carton, wearing a "Ready for Her" shirt, and pretending like a work truck leaking oil is the moral equivalent of invading Libya while you cook yer eggs like a liberal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried cooking egg whites in the carton, and it took me a while to figure it out, but they finally cooked through and were quite delicious. I had made the mistake of opening up the top and leaving off the lid and they just weren't cooking, but then I realized that they needed the steam so I put the lid back on and sealed the top with a binder clip and voila! Definitely plan to try this method again once my current carton isn't so full, because clean up was a dream.